# Why is this javascript code making browser draw 50% CPU and so much memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, memory

I have this banner rotator code:

```
function ban_rot() {
    //First preload images
    // counter
    var i = 0;

    // create object
    imageObj = new Image();

    // set image list
    images = new Array();
    images[0] = "../Graphics/adv/1.gif"
    images[1] = "../Graphics/adv/2.jpg"

    // start preloading
    for (i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
        imageObj.src = images[i];
    }
    ///////////////////////
    var links = new Array("http://www.link1.com", "http://www.link2.se");
    var alts = new Array("alt1", "alt2");
    var titles = new Array("title1", "title2");

    var counter = 0;
    var banner_div = document.getElementById("ban_rot");
    cycle();

    function cycle() {
        if (counter == links.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        else if (counter < links.length) {
            banner_div.innerHTML = '<a href=\"' + links[counter] + '\"><img src=\"' + images[counter] + '\" border=\"1px\" style=\"border-color:#000;\" alt=\"' + alts[counter] + '\" title=\"' + titles[counter] + '\"></a>';
            //increase counter
            counter++;
        }
        setInterval(cycle, 8000);
    } //end cycle function
} //end ban_rot function
```

With this code, after around 2-3 minutes in Firefox or Chrome, the memory goes up and cpu goes to around 50%.
The computer gets laggy and I have to terminate Chrome and FF.

Is there any reason for this in this code above?

Thanks

Comment: Functions inside functions are fine if that's what the situation calls for.  Here, the counter and links array are private, so a function outside of `ban_rot` wouldn't have access to them.  The only way around that without creating a closure would be to pollute the namespace and hope no one has more than one banner rotator (or any other code that might use the same variables) in a page.  With that said, though, i'm a bit uncomfortable with closures with names.

Comment: You guys are nuts. There's absolutely nothing wrong with functions inside functions, and that "closure with a name" is perfectly safe because it's done as a function declaration statement, not as a "named anonymous function" (which are problematic due to poor implementations).

Comment: yes, functions in functions is the most AWESOME feature of javascript.

Comment: Oh also @Camran: when declaring an array, you should get in the habit of writing `var a = [value, value, value];` instead of using `new Array(...);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead of [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) here, like this:

```
setTimeout(cycle, 8000);
```

With [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) you're queuing more and more stacks of the function each time, rather than calling it once 8 seconds later, we're queueing another interval timer to run every 8 seconds, so you're getting this:

- 8 seconds: 1 run
- 16 seconds: 2 runs
- 24 seconds: 4 runs
- 32 seconds: 8 runs
- ...uh oh

With [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) you'll get just one run when the timer is up, not an *additional* run every 8 seconds.

To be clear, this happens *because* you're calling it each time it runs, with normal one-time usage this wouldn't be an issue, there's nothing inherently evil with [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

Comment: On first glance, this sounds a bit like there was a problem with `setInterval()` in general, but in fact the OP was just doing it wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak - you're right it does read that way, let me clarify a bit that it's specific to the usage.